# Unity: How to limit the rotation of the z axis using Wheel Joint 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-engine, game-development

I am creating a Jump and run game but you are driving with a car. I use the the Wheel Joint 2D collider and I am also able to jump. Here is my code for the movement:

```
void Update()
{
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
    {
        carRb.velocity = new Vector2(carRb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && carRb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        carRb.velocity = new Vector2(carRb.velocity.x, carRb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    backTire.AddTorque(-movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    frontTire.AddTorque(-movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    carRb.AddTorque(-movement * carTorque * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

It works just fine but when I am fast and jump I rotate completely around my own axis and I land on my head and can't move anymore. Therefore I want to limit the rotation of the z-axis to a certain degree so that it won't happen anymore. I looked up how to do it but it doesn't fit for my car-context. Do you have any idea?
I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to solve this:

- Freeze the rotation axis on the rigibody (very limiting option)
- Detect the faulty position as "upside-down + grounded" and respawn the vehicle after 2s
- Forcefully rotate the vehicle back to normal rotation when it's grounded (not in air anymore, so you still allow flips in the air)
- Limit the angle via script.

Last thing could be done like this:

```
Vector3 eulerRot = rb.rotation.eulerAngles; // read current rotation
eulerRot.z = Mathf.Clamp(eulerRot .y, minRotation, maxRotation); // clamp it only on z axis.
rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerRot); // set clamped rotation
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Yeah I also froze it but as you say it's very limiting :D

The second option sounds not bad but I kinda feel like it happens too often and can get annoying when you respawn.

How would you rotate the vehicle back to normal rotation?

I tried the code but it says that eulerAngles doesn't accept float values or vice-versa. Any idea? :D

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to convert back to Quaternion. Changed the code to `Quaternion.Euler(eulerRot)` to fix it.